# Devise: submit form after successfull login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Can some one shed some lights on how can I resolve this problem?

Using `Devise` in a rails app.

1. A user is not signed in.
2. He/she fills in a form and clicks the `submit` button.
3. The login window pop ups before the `create` action:

   `before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create]`

**Problem:**

After the successful login the user get redirected to the home page and his/her enteries in the form get lost.

How can I remember the session to submit the form after a successful sign in?

*Note:* I can resolve this problem with a nasty hack, but I prefer to have a better solution.

Comment: You can only submit the form with `GET` method!

Comment: I'd like to do this, too - wouldn't mind hearing how you solved this.

Comment: unfortunately I still don't have a proper solution for this, the ugly solution would be to save the from entries as json data into a tmp file...